# Display data from two MySQL database tables

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first attempt at PHP PDO. I needed to get data from two tables in my MySQL database. I'm pleased to say the code works, and I was just wondering if what I've done is correct.

```
<?php

// MySQL Database Connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// Display Data
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM data1 LEFT JOIN data2 ON data1.id = data2.id WHERE data1.id=1') as $row) {
    // Data is displayed in their respected places.
}

?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description">
<meta name="author" content="Author">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['sample1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sample2']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['extra1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['extra2']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working code as, at a minimum, you would need another  iteration through data set to echo out the results to the table. Show your whole code.

Comment: Yes it is, the code is working on my end, the above is the whole code from my php file, the only thing "missing" is my database dump.

Comment: If you think something is "missing" in the code please can you expand on this, thank you very much.

Comment: The is no code inside your for each that deals with the result set.

Comment: It's working for me though.

Answer (score 2):

### foreach

Don't have an empty foreach loop... ever. Similarly, just because php lets `$row` escape from the context it is in does not mean you should use it after the `foreach`-loop is over.

### PDO::query

I recommend against using `PDO::query`, especially because you lack a thorough understanding of what you are doing. You can use it when executing complete static queries (those that do not have variables), but you already have a where-clause in that sql statement and it is only a matter of time until you want to change that to something dynamic. Use [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead.

### PDO::prepare

You are using `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`. Good. Except that you do not use prepared statements at all. Keep in mind that your mysql driver must be able to use native prepared statements too.

### PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

You are setting the error mode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Good. Except that you do not catch any of them and instead let the page return blank.